# Git won't successfully install for my windows WSL environment

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try and install git for my local Windows Subsystem Linux Distribution. I'm using Linux 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft x86_64 (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS).

```
agrant@ANGUS-GRANT:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/Documents/GitHub$ sudo apt-get install git
[sudo] password for agrant:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
agrant@ANGUS-GRANT:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/Documents/GitHub$ git --version
The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install git
agrant@ANGUS-GRANT:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/Documents/GitHub/lens-starter-st$ echo $PATH
/home/agrant/bin:/home/agrant/.local/bin:/home/agrant/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Kaspersky Lab/Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Windows:/mnt/c/Go/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/atom/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/go/bin:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/AppData/Local/Programs/Fiddler:/mnt/c/Users/agrant/go/bin:/snap/bin
```

but when i try and run it, it says not "installed" please advise?

Comment: Can you try running `hash -r` and then updating your question to include the output of `which git`?

Comment: Hello @bk2204 thanks for your update i ran both commands above but didn't see any output (at least not to the command line) .

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` produce?

Comment: Thanks @bk2204 I have updated my answer above to show the $PATH. It looks like 'git' is shown.